# Nodemailer - form validation with submit

Tags: javascript, validation, nodemailer

that's my connect page's form. it works great. but i want to validate in validation function line (validate() ) ,too. however, it is sending mail even though empty inputs.

i think, i have to add something in handleSubmit line with isValid line.

what should I do?

```
const initialState={
    name: "",
    subject: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
    sent:false,
    nameError: "",
}

export default class Validation extends React.Component {

  state = initialState;

  handleName = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      name:e.target.value
    })
  }

  validate = () => {
    let nameError= "";

    if (!this.state.name) {
      nameError = "Name cannot be blank!"
    }

    if (nameError) {
      this.setState({ nameError });
      return false;
  }  

  return true;
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const isValid = this.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(this.state);
    }
    
    this.sendingMail();
    
  }

  sendingMail=()=>{
    let data = {
      name:this.state.name,
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/form',data)
    .then(res=>{
      this.setState({
        sent:true,
      },this.resetForm())
    })
    .catch(()=> {
      console.log('message not sent');
    })
  }
```

Comment: "*what should i do?*" It seems you should only be calling `this.sendingMail()` when `isValid` is true. Am I missing something? Why not move that invocation into the `if` block you have?

Comment: because sending mail dont working if i dont calling this.sendingMail() in handleSubmit.

Comment: I’m not sure you’re understanding my comment, as I didn’t suggest you move your invocation of `this.sendingMail()` outside of `handleSubmit()`. Rather, I suggested to move it into your pre-existing `if` block so that it’s only invoked when the validation passes.

Comment: oh okay, i moved it pre-if block but nothing changed.

Comment: i think, i need to add something in if( isValid ) that prevents the sendingMail() from working but i didn't found.

Comment: Again, it seems you’re misinterpreting what I’m trying to convey here. Why not move it *inside* the `if (isValid) {...}` block...?

Comment: Yeah, it is solved! Thank you so much dude.